# ApplesScript: Remove a range of characters between two defined ones

Tags: applescript

I have a string like the one below and I'd like to remove the range of characters that looks like this: `28%57%85%`, `20%40%59%79%99%` on every other line.

```
'/Users/studiotwo/Desktop/Test/originals/
  analyzing ...
    [1/33] "003.wav": 28%57%85%-12.3 LUFS (-10.7 LU)
        peak: 0.0 TPFS, range: 0.0 LU
    [2/33] "04.wav": 28%57%85%-19.8 LUFS (-3.2 LU)
        peak: -3.5 TPFS, range: 0.0 LU
    [3/33] "pb_1.wav": 28%57%85%-13.9 LUFS (-9.1 LU)
        peak: 0.2 TPFS, range: 0.0 LU
    [4/33] "pb_10.wav": 20%40%59%79%99%-22.1 LUFS (-0.9 LU)
        peak: -3.2 TPFS, range: -23.1 LU
    [5/33] "pb_11.wav": 25%51%76%-22.0 LUFS (-1.0 LU)
        peak: -6.4 TPFS, range: 0.0 LU
    [6/33] "pb_12.wav": 24%47%71%94%-21.9 LUFS (-1.1 LU)
        peak: -3.5 TPFS, range: -22.1 LU
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `do shell script` to run a sed command like `sed 's/": [^-]*/: /"'`:

```
set input to "'/Users/studiotwo/Desktop/Test/originals/
  analyzing ...
    [1/33] \"003.wav\": 28%57%85%-12.3 LUFS (-10.7 LU)
        peak: 0.0 TPFS, range: 0.0 LU
    [2/33] \"04.wav\": 28%57%85%-19.8 LUFS (-3.2 LU)
        peak: -3.5 TPFS, range: 0.0 LU
    [3/33] \"pb_1.wav\": 28%57%85%-13.9 LUFS (-9.1 LU)
        peak: 0.2 TPFS, range: 0.0 LU
    [4/33] \"pb_10.wav\": 20%40%59%79%99%-22.1 LUFS (-0.9 LU)
        peak: -3.2 TPFS, range: -23.1 LU
    [5/33] \"pb_11.wav\": 25%51%76%-22.0 LUFS (-1.0 LU)
        peak: -6.4 TPFS, range: 0.0 LU
    [6/33] \"pb_12.wav\": 24%47%71%94%-21.9 LUFS (-1.1 LU)
        peak: -3.5 TPFS, range: -22.1 LU"
do shell script "sed 's/\": [^-]*/\": /' <<< " & quoted form of input without altering line endings
```

Note that the `do shell script` command returns an error if `input` is longer than `getconf ARG_MAX` (or currently 2^18) bytes. `without altering line endings` disables converting line endings to CR.